# Using Dundas.Charting in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dundas

I am getting the following exception, while using Dundas.Charting in Asp.Net:-

```
Stack trace:    
   at Dundas.Charting.WebControl.ChartHttpHandler.b(HttpContext )
   at Dundas.Charting.WebControl.ChartHttpHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I am using it in, IIS 7.0 (integrated mode), while web.config has all the necessary attributes there as well such as following:-

Under appSettings

```
1. add key="ChartHttpHandler" value="Storage=memory;Timeout=180;Url=~/temp/;"
```

Under httpHandlers

```
2. add path="ChartAxd.axd" verb="*" type="Dundas.Charting.WebControl.ChartHttpHandler" validate="false"
```

Under handlers

```
3. add name="ChartAxd.axd" path="ChartAxd.axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Dundas.Charting.WebControl.ChartHttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"
```

While, I am using the same replica of code and web.config on another server, all things work fine. Am I missing something on IIS? Looking forward to hear from you.
Many thanks.

Comment: the message that you give is the stack trace (not the error). Do you double check that your asp.net have full permission to write on temp directory ?

Comment: Error Message which I am receiving is :- Object reference not set to an instance of an object. While, the scenario which i discussed is my production envoirnment having Web farm ( 2 servers only). Result from one server is coming fine, while from another I faced the above mentioned problem. Same rights are applied to both temp folder of both machines. While, asp.net permission are not applied on both of the servers of temp folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is because you use the `Storage=memory;`, change it to `Storage=file;` as:

```
<add key="ChartHttpHandler" value="Storage=file;Timeout=60; Url=~/Tempo/;Dir=c:\Inetpub\vhosts\sitename\httpdocs\Tempo\" />
```

Also add both directories for be sure, the `~/Tempo`, and the direct full path to be saved them.